# matplotlib: how can I make an opaque filled region that covers what's underneath?

Tags: python, matplotlib

For instance, if I do this:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt
x = np.linspace(0,10)
y = x**2
z = 50*np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.fill_between(x,z,facecolor='r')
plt.show()
```

then the line plot is still visible underneath the shaded region.  Is there a way to make the shaded region entirely block what's underneath it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [zorder](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_zorder):

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 10)
y = x**2
z = 50*np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.fill_between(x, z, facecolor='r', zorder=3)
plt.show()
```

[image]